# Maximum number of cursors exceeded on calling Package Stored Procedures

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle package which contains 3 stored procedures, ini_pkg, add_concept, add_imp with which I want to fill some lists and then work with the data stored in them. For each concept I call the respective procedure, but after 300 insertions an exception is thrown.

```
@Override
    public boolean save(XX fact) {
        try {
            StoredProcedureQuery query = manager.createStoredProcedureQuery("COM.TEST.INI_PKG");
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("UUID", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.setParameter("UUID", fact.getUuid());
            query.execute();

            if (fact.getConcepts() != null && !fact.getConcepts().isEmpty()) {
                for (Iterator<Concept> iterator = fact.getConcepts().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    Concept concept = iterator.next();

                    StoredProcedureQuery addQuery = manager
                            .createStoredProcedureQuery("COM.TEST.ADD_CONCEPT");
                    addQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("P_CLAVPROD", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
                    addQuery.setParameter("P_CLAVPROD", concept.getClaveProdServ());
                    addQuery.execute();

                    if (concept.getImp() != null && !concept.getImp().isEmpty()) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }

            ...

            queryInsert.execute();
            manager.close();
        } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
            System.out.println("Error : " + pe.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The sored procedures in package

```
TYPE R_CONCEPTO IS RECORD (
    CLAVPRODSERV VARCHAR2(20)
    timpuesto T_IMPUESTO
);
TYPE T_CONCEPT IS TABLE OF R_CONCEPT;
tconcept T_CONCEPT;

PROCEDURE INI_PKG(UUID IN VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    IDFAC := COM.SEQ_IDFACT.NEXTVAL;
    P_UUID := UUID;
    tconcept := t_concept();
  END INI_PKG;

  PROCEDURE ADD_CONCEPT(P_CLAVPROD IN VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
      tconcept.EXTEND; 
      tconcept(tconcept.LAST).CLAVPRODSERV := P_CLAVEPROD;
  END ADD_CONCEPT;
```

I dont know why I am getting the maximum number of cursors exceeded (the max is 300). Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Java expert but make sure you close your cursors when done with them. Oracle has a maximum of concurrent open cursors. It can be set higher, but it is good practice to close them. Can you close the addQuery in your java loop after execution?